# Impicit function can't be injected

Tags: scala, function, implicit

I have the following code:

```
case class Number (value:Int)
```

and

```
class Calculator {
  def performCalc( input:Number)(implicit calc: (Number=>Number) ) =  calc(input)
}
```

Now, when I, in a specs2 test try this:

```
class CalculatorTest extends mutable.Specification {
  "Calculator" should {
    "*  Accept explicit calculation parameter" in {
      implicit val addTwelve = (input: Number) => Number(input.value + 12)
      val calc = new Calculator()

      val result = calc.performCalc(Number(4))
      result must beEqualTo(16)
    }
  }
}
```

I expected the 'addTwelve' function to be injected implicitly as a parameter of performCalc. However, I get the following failure:

```
Error:(49, 42) ambiguous implicit values:
 both method $conforms in object Predef of type [A]=> <:<[A,A]
 and value addTwelve of type nl.example.Number => nl.example.Number
 match expected type nl.example.Number => nl.example.Number
      val result = calc.performCalc(Number(4))
                             ^
```

What am I doing wrong? It should be possible to use methods as implicits, right?

Scala: 2.11.7

Comment: it looks like there is already an implicit in Predef that has an applicable signature ([A]=> <:<[A,A]), so your implicit is the second that matches the signature (thus, ambiguous).

Comment: Problem is that that would match every A=>A function. How could I ever inject an impliciy A=>A?

Comment: This article covers good style conventions and it gives an example as to why the implicit identity function exists. See sections near listings 21.2 through 21.5: https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is technically a valid use of implicit, but it's not a very *strong* use case. Specifically, there is a pre-existing implicit that provides Number=>Number. The compiler is having trouble telling which implicit method you *really* want.

What's better is to wrap this method into a trait as a "tag" for the implicit type.

```
case class Number(value: Int)
trait CalcMethod {
  def perform(n: Number): Number
}
class Calculator {
  def performCalc(input:Number)(implicit calc: CalcMethod) = calc.perform(input)
}

class CalculatorTest extends mutable.Specification {
  "Calculator" should {
    "*  Accept explicit calculation parameter" in {
      implicit val addTwelve: CalcMethod = new CalcMethod { 
          def perform(input: Number) = Number(input.value + 12) 
      }
      val result = new Calculator().performCalc(Number(4))
      result must beEqualTo(16)
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is maybe closer to what you want:

```
case class Number(value: Int)
implicit class CalcMethod(val perform: Number => Number)
class Calculator {
  def performCalc(input:Number)(implicit calc: CalcMethod) = calc.perform(input)
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
implicit val addTwelve: CalcMethod = (input: Number) => Number(input.value + 12) 
val result = new Calculator().performCalc(Number(4))
```

Comment: That there already exists a different Number class (from a different package) is irrelevant and has no impact on the implicit. The compiler knows very well which Number I want. Most definitly not :java.lang.Number. In fact, it doesn't matter what I name the 'Number' class.  Also, I know how to wrap it in a class, but I don't want to. I explicitly want to use a function. Why waste code on extra classes when functions are first class citizens?  ```implicit val addTwelve = (input: Number) =>  Number(input.value + 12) ``` is far nicer ..

Comment: The implicit that it's finding is an identity implicit. Specifically an implicit method that provides A=>A for all A. I never said anything about a duplicate Number class.

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out that injecting implicit Functions is poor style. You're not "wasting" anything by using classes, but rather making it more explicit to users what exactly you want to be implicitly provided.

Comment: K, then I misunderstood that part of your answer. But, I already knew this. Since that is what the error message states. But isn't there a way around this? Why is it that scala seems to have made it impossible to use an implicit identity function ? (Thanks to $conforms apparently)

Comment: Actually, it is wasting: I'm programming functionally , and wrapping a class around it does not make it more clearer. How would wrapping a class around it, make it more 'explicit' than that single line?

Ps. just to be clear, I am not attacking you, just stating my view.

Comment: See my edit, I think maybe this is closer to what you want?

Comment: Definitely. Too bad pm is not available, cause I would like to ask you some more about this.